# How to Show String values on yaxis of highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of a data that contains currency symbols ie. series =[1000 $, 2000 $, 56577$]. How can i force the yaxis labels to only show these values

Comment: Is it always `$` after? You'd want to only have the value in your data and then include the `$` in the labels with `format` or `formatter`.

Comment: @Ondkloss not always $. it can be any curreny symbol.i want to show these values in labels without using the formatter.the symbol can be a prefix or suffix based on the currency itself.

Comment: @Sankar I think you should follow Ondkloss's advice and try to add (prefix or suffix) whatever currency symbol you want to that number. But, if this is not helpful to you, it's better explain your scenario in more detailed manner and try to show some code as well :)

Comment: Generally your form is incorrect, because you cannot set number and string in that way. Maybe better is prepare simple parser which remove your currency sign and then use formatter like Ondkloss suggests